# Why did Fermat publish so little?

Tags: math-history

Fermat published very little during his lifetime. Why is this the case?

Comment: I believe he was a judge and math was only his hobby.

Comment: He mostly investigated curiosities, and letters were typically considered formal ways of preserving information, so they were good enough.

Comment: @Noam Yes, it's true he was a judge. But even if he considered math as a hobby, it still strikes me a bit odd that he published so little, especially considering the pivotal work he did.

Comment: @JasonM and Noam: do you have any source or quote from Fermat in which he explains his lack of incentive to publish?

Comment: He didn't have sheet of papers where he could wrote what he wanted to publicate. lol

Comment: The first “scientific journal” was the [Journal des sçavans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_des_sçavans), founded 1665, a few months after the death of Fermat. He wrote some essays and memoirs; some of his works were published posthumous. The usage in those times was very different from nowadays.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on History of Science and Mathematics

Comment: @egreg's comment is spot on: bravo!  For anybody knowing French the reference to and spelling of  *sçavans* (now written *savants*) is pure bliss.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I did not know the "History of Science and Mathematics" Stack Exchange page existed! Thank you for the pointer.